# Eigenvalues of $A^H$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition

I know that the eigenvalues of the conjugate transpose of a matrix are the conjugates of that matrix. For real matrices the conjugate transpose is just the transpose and the taking the transpose doesn't change the determinant so the eigenvalues must be the same. Is there a similar intuition for complex matrices?

Comment: Hint: complex roots of polynomials come in conjugate pairs. Also take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53591/complex-conjugates-and-complex-eigenvalues

Comment: The same argument works for complex matrices: $\det(A^* - \lambda I) = \overline{\det(A - \overline{\lambda}I)}$

Comment: The determinant is a polynomial, so 
$$
\det(\overline{A^T} - \overline{\lambda} I) = \overline{\det(A^T - \lambda I)}.
$$